# I'm trying to print a char to a output file, however, my compilers says I'm printing an int

Tags: c, io, printf

> Pass1.c: In function ‘main’:
>
> Pass1.c:53:6: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
>
> ```
>  fprintf(ofp,"%s", curr);
> ```

There's the exact error I'm getting. I'm trying to print curr to an output file using fprintf. I run the program and try to output from my input file and I end up getting s segmentation fault. I'm using c for the first time and have no idea whats going on. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void main() {
    int qflag, zflag, punctflag;
    int skip;
    int orgChar, decChar, codeChar; //# of original characters, decoded characters, and code sequences
    double perDec;
    FILE *ifp, *ofp; //input & output file pointers 
    char filename[30], curr; // filename and the current character input from the file

    printf("Enter the filename to be scanned:  ");   // ask user for filename
    scanf("%s", filename);   //user filename input

    ifp = fopen(filename, "r"); // open the file as read-only
    ofp = fopen("output.txt", "w"); // open output file as write-only

    while ((curr = getc(ifp)) != EOF) {    // get the next char and as long as it is not the EOF, continue

        if (qflag && isdigit(curr)) { //qflag is true and is digit is true
            skip = (int) curr - 48; //skip # of digits 
            codeChar++; //add to coded char index
            qflag = 0; //qflag now flase 
        } else if (qflag) {  //if q isnt followed by a interger
            fprintf(ofp, "q"); //print q
            decChar++; //added to the decoded index
            qflag = 0; //qflag now false
        }

        if (punctflag == 1 && isdigit(curr)) {
            skip = (int) curr - 48;
            punctflag = 0;
        }
        //If there is a special case where we have something z^g the else would be here

        if (zflag && ispunct(curr)) {
            punctflag = 1;
            codeChar += 2;
            zflag = 0;
        } else if (zflag) {
            fprintf(ofp, "z");
            decChar++;
            zflag = 0;
        }
        //must put in the X variable!!!!!!!!!!
        if (curr == 'q' || curr == 'Q') {
            qflag = 1;
        } else if (curr == 'z' || curr == 'Z') {
            zflag = 1;
        }

        if (zflag == 0 && qflag == 0 && skip == 0) { //need x here
            fprintf(ofp, "%s", curr); //<------ getting issue here!
            decChar++;
        } else {
            skip--;
        }
    }

    fclose(ifp); //closes input file
    fclose(ofp); //closes output file
}
```

Comment: `%s` is for a string.  You want `%c` for a character.

Comment: Moreover, you actually do need `curr` to be an `int`.  That is the type that `getc()` returns, and you need to use that type to be able to distinguish `EOF` from a potentially-valid character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition is:

```
char filename[30], curr;
```

Here `filename` is an array but `curr` is not. Here is what is correct if you want to put a string:

```
char filename[30], curr[size];
```

But you want to put a char only. In this case, don't touch to the definiton of the curr above and instead change the `fprintf` section as follows:

```
fprintf(ofp,"%c", curr);
```

`%s` is not okay because you are going to put a char, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
fprintf(ofp,"%s", curr);
```

to

```
fprintf(ofp,"%c", curr);
```

to print a single character.

---

Additional comments: You should use `int main(void)` instead of `void main()` and the variables `perDec` and `decChar` are not used in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is in here

> Pass1.c: In function ‘main’:
>
> Pass1.c:53:6: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’,
>   but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]

This is actually telling you that you used `'%s'` to print but you should use `'%c'`.

So all you have to do is change:
`fprintf(ofp, "%s", curr);` to `fprintf(ofp, "%c", curr);`

Your compiler basically said it all, you simply had to read the warning. It is also just a warning so it still compiles even though it is not correct. These warnings are here to help you.